# Transactions go to an older contract address rather than the present deployed one

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, ethereumjs

Though I have deployed a new contract but the transactions go to a previously deployed contract in my application. I'm attaching the screenshot of my Remix-ide code and the code for the front end application.I'm newly learning blockchain from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djRxq7Q7xBk&list=PLsyeobzWxl7oY6tZmnZ5S7yTDxyu4zDW-&index=22 . Please help me out :(
[image]

These are the codes to my front file

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>

        <p>Your balance:</p>
        <p id='balance'></p>
        <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Enter amount here">
        <button id="deposit">Deposit</button>
        <button id="withdraw">Withdraw</button>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is my app.js file

```
var contract;
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    web3=new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

```
var address='0x74c3847bfb1a0662dcf4c49a88e5001ed076d89c'; //Deployed Contract address
var abi=[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "amt",
                "type": "int256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Deposit",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "amt",
                "type": "int256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Withdrawl",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "GetBalance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "int256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

contract=new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
contract.methods.GetBalance().call().then(function(bal){
    $('#balance').html(bal);
})
```

})
//Depositing money
$('#deposit').click(function()
{
    var amt=0;
    amt=parseInt($('#amount').val());

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function (accounts)
{
    var acc=accounts[0];
    return contract.methods.Deposit(amt).send({ from: acc});                    
}).then(function(tx){
    console.log(tx);
}).catch(function(tx)
{
    console.log(tx);

})
```

})
//Withdrawing money
$('#withdraw').click(function()
{
    var amt=0;
    amt=parseInt($('#amount').val());

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function (accounts)
{
    var acc=accounts[0];
    return contract.methods.Withdrawl(amt).send({ from: acc});                    
}).then(function(tx){
    console.log(tx);
}).catch(function(tx)
{
    console.log(tx);

})
```

})

This my front end application and the screenshot of the metamask popup

[image: I have marked the address of the contract which is not the current address of the contract in my remix-ide.]

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser cache or force refresh by Ctrl-F5 or something?

Comment: @hellopeach Nope,clearing all kinda cache doesn't ring a bell. Changing the web3 provider to ganache localhost 7545 gives another error : Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
I tried using web3js version from 1.0.0-beta.36 to 1.0.0-beta.35 and it shows a new error : Uncaught (in promise) Error: Couldn't decode  from ABI: 0x

Comment: The easiest way to check if your code is not caching the old value is to just right click "view page source" in chrome, then click on your app.js in there and see if the code actually points to the correct address you wanted.